# Unable to connect to mysql from host virtual machine

Tags: mysql, networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

$ mysql -u testuser -h 192.168.57.5 -p

Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.57.1' (using password: YES)

On virtual guest i had already given permissions to mysql user with below command:

> GRANT ALL ON DB.* TO root@192.168.57.5 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

But above is not working.

Below Solution is working:

> GRANT ALL ON DB.* TO root@192.168.57.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

**My Quetion is why i need to grant permissions to root@192.168.57.1?**

My IP address of virtual machine is 192.168.57.5.

**In MySQL Config:**

bind-address = 192.168.57.5

I can access my virtual machine apache server with ip 192.168.57.5 and mysql server too with 192.168.57.5.

But i have to grant permissions to 192.168.57.1 in MySQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this has been answered many times but here it goes one more time...

When you grant privileges, you grant them to the user that **is connecting**. What you are doing above is granting access to your `MySQL` server.

> GRANT ALL ON DB.* TO root@192.168.57.5 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Means **grant all** to user **root** who's IP is **192.168.57.5**

When you grant access to your client that wishes to use the server, it magically works.

Answer (score 0):

**In My vitual box:**

Host Manager IP: 192.168.57.1 and

Client Machine IP : 192.168.57.5

In order to access MySQL from Client machine. I have to provide Grant permissions for Host Manager network IP address instead of virtual machine ip address.

That's why below works:

> GRANT ALL ON DB.* TO root@192.168.57.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';